# Image Bitmap gets rotated when loaded from camera/gallery [Android 9]

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-bitmap

I am loading the image from gallery or camera so that I can edit it. I have used EXIFInterface to manage the rotation of bitmap. But in Samsung s8[Android 9], it provides 90 degree rotation for the image but Image is originally not rotated. And depending on this rotation I rotate it 90 degree which I don't want.

I have tried using ContentResolver to get rotation through cursor but it also has same problem as EXIFInterface. Following are the both methods I tried to fix the problem:

```
private static int getExifOrientation(String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return RotationOptions.ROTATE_90;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return RotationOptions.ROTATE_180;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return RotationOptions.ROTATE_270;
            default:
                return RotationOptions.NO_ROTATION;
    }
}

 private static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        try {
            Uri imageContentUri = getImageContentUri(context, photoUri.getPath());
            if (imageContentUri == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageContentUri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
                cursor.close();
                return -1;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
            return orientation;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this happens try cropping the image use crop image code before setting it to imageview...

Comment: What is your question? Bear in mind that there is no requirement for camera apps to record accurate EXIF headers in the images that they capture.

Comment: Can you provide the code for this ? as I dont have control over crop as its third party library... This is fact that after I use crop feature it get correct orientation.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to get proper orientation of the Image but can't get in Android 9.. It tells image is rotated but it's not.

Comment: What is your evidence that this has something to do with Android 9.0? How many different Android 9.0 devices did you test, and from how many manufacturers? Where did the image come from, and did you check that image manually to see what sort of EXIF headers are in it?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tested it thoroughy on Samsung s8[android 9] and Nokia 6.1[Android 9] also produced the Issue more than once... I took the picture form phone's native camera... then went into app and picked it from gallery, and check EXIF through above given code.

Comment: Try a different camera app, such as OpenCamera. Try that same camera app on multiple devices across multiple OS versions. If the single camera app provides EXIF headers across versions, then the problem is not with the OS version, but with the camera apps that you were testing previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195487/discussion-between-sohail-khan-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem. I managed without EXIFInterface,

By rotating image with this condition -

```
if (bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight()) {
            bm = rotateImage(bm, 270);
        }
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

Comment: If the image was actually landscape it will make it portrait.

Comment: That's the problem that EXIF doesn't provide right orientation. So Image rotation will be effected.